# How to prevent image overflowing flex-grow-1 item?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]Hi I have issue wizh my image.

### I have 3 sections:

### Header

### IMG + other (main section)

button

---

Now... I have to set image heigth at maximum-height: 100% of container size.
This container has class from bootstrap flex-grow-1 to fill empty space between sections. Problem is that image is overflowing this section. Please How to solve this issue?

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-browser-d5qrr?file=/index.html&fbclid=IwAR3LXPTNfumRyitqed-xzOJHEeq5PBTuLnU-V0LH-4UB8QIbPdb_hZKL1G0

This is what I have to do but image is overflowing now so I hide it. Width could be lesser than 100% width of container. The  ratio height:width should be same as in original image.

[image]

Comment: I have Top, bottom and mid parts as you can see in html. I just need to fill mid section with image (not overflowing this section). In code sandbox I put overflow hidden on container if you comment it you will sii the problem

Comment: And you want that your 3 parts will not be heighter than your `.custom-container` ?

Comment: Yes. Custom container has width and height :         max-width: 800px;
        max-height: 400px;
        width: 70%;
        height: 60%;

Comment: this is important

Comment: Ok and the 3 part need to be responsive (the image can be smaller if you resize the window smaller) ?

Comment: Yes....  The mid section just filling the empty space between top and bottom. So Image should be responsive too in this way

Comment: The image don 't need to fill full width in mid section. It should save correct ratio when resizing

Comment: I think the key is set height of image at 100% of mid section but it not work as I except

Answer (score 1):

I remove (I think) all bootstrap class to obtain a "simple code". This is what I already achieve.

EDIT: to obtain 1 column I add `flex-direction: column;` to `.bigDiv`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .bigDiv {
        max-width: 800px;
        max-height: 400px;
        width: 70%;
        height: 60%;
        border: 4px solid red;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
      }
      .div2 {
        border: 2px solid green;
        min-height: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bigDiv">
      <div class="div1">
        <h1>Nadpis</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <img
          src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhtml.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fvery-large-flamingo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1"
          alt="img"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="div3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Dalej</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer to do this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <style>
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
        }
        .custom-container{
            max-width:800px;
            max-height:400px;
            width:70%;
            height:60%;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }  
        .mid{
            border:2px solid green;
            min-height:0;
        }
        img{
            max-height:100%;
            max-width: 100%;;
        }

        #problem{
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-container d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="top">
            <h1>Nadpis</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mid flex-grow-1 d-flex">
            <div id="problem" class="w-100" >
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhtml.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fvery-large-flamingo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="img">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Dalej</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```